# Error with python string formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a script that takes a text file containing IP addresses (one per line) and then passes each IP into a non-Python program command.

The result is an error:

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

```
import subprocess
list='c:\cmc_list.txt'

with open(list,'r') as cmc_list:

for i in cmc_list:
  racadm_command = "racadm -r %s -u root -p calvin getslotname" % i

output = subprocess.Popen(racadm_command % i, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, 
 shell=True).communicate()[0]

print(racadm_command, output)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please be sure to post properly indented code, especially for `python` questions, where indentation matters.

Comment: What are the values in the text file? Has the file run properly in the past? Were there any edits since?

Comment: What is `racadm_command % i` supposed to do that isn't already done?

Comment: I'm with @cricket_007. I don't think the extra `% i` is needed after `racadm_command`.

Comment: By the way, you should avoid naming variables as `list` or any other Python data type

Comment: You're only calling Popen with the last value in cmc_list.  Is that intended, or should the following lines also be indented?

Comment: besides removing `%i` in `Popen`, have you tried using f-strings (literal string interpolation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string passed to the Popen command has already been formatted, so it has no % left to consume the i.  Take away the "% i" and I think you'll be fine.

Comment: Thank you.  Removing the % i from Popen allowed the script to run.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you meant to do the formatting only once

```
import subprocess
cmc_list='c:\cmc_list.txt'

racadm_command_template = "racadm -r {} -u root -p calvin getslotname"

with open(cmc_list,'r') as f:
    for ip in f:
        cmd = racadm_command_template.format(ip)
        output = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()

        print(cmd, output[0])
```

I also suggest using `getpass` for your password prompt, or import from an environment variable. Additionally, don't print out the password and please change it from the default

Comment: Thank you.  Your version of the script runs successfully.  This is my first python script.  Its purely educational so password handling was not a priority but I do appreciate the tip.  I'm assuming you are familiar with the targets here since you know its the default password.  I'm curious about your choices to replace cmc_list with f and i with ip; also moving the [0] from the output definition to the print function.Why those choices?

Comment: Upon further inspection.  For every IP in the list with the exception of the last it executes the command prematurely; so what should be "racadm -r %s -u root -p calvin getslotname" winds up being "racadm -r %s" on all but last IP in list.  Thoughts?

Comment: `i` is commonly used as a numeric iterator, not a line in a file, while `f` is a "file object". Variable names aren't too important otherwise, but `list` is a builtin Python type, so you wouldn't have been able to use the `list()` function otherwise. I moved the [0] so you could also access the other values of the output, if needed. Regarding the final line, I'm not using %s here, but I don't think that should happen

Comment: please see above

Comment: Please post a new question rather than edit one you already accepted.